# Oracle ojdbc executeBatch too slow

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I want batch insert 20000 records, the code is blew:

```
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(";"));
                System.out.println(line);
                st.addBatch(line);

                i += 1;
                if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("execute：" + i);
                    Date beginBatch = new Date();
                    st.executeBatch();
                    Date endBatch = new Date();
                    System.out.println("Start at: " + beginBatch);
                    System.out.println("End at: " + endBatch);
                }
            }
```

and it tooks me one hour to finished, but when i run this sql file in Sql Developer console, it only tooks me 3 minutes. Is there anything wrong. Could someone help me to figure out the root cause.

Comment: 3 minute is very slow for 200,000 record.

Comment: How to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database JDBC uses array parameters to implement JDBC batch execute. There are no parameters so nothing to batch. Your batch execute just queues up the statements and executes them one at a time, no batch.

Still an hour to execute 20,000 SQL statements sounds a bit slow even if the database has to do a hard parse on each SQL. Since SQLDev can do the same work in 3 minutes JDBC should do the same. The big difference is batching. The driver batching code is not free. It imposes substantial overhead. I'd recommend that you replace the addBatch call with a call to execute. That will probably be faster.

Answer (score -1):

You never clear your batch. So probably at the first execution you exec 1000 statements, at the 2nd 2000 and so on...

You should do it adding something like

```
                Date beginBatch = new Date();
                st.executeBatch();
                st.clearBatch();
```

Comment: Execute batch should clear the batch after execution (even if unsuccessful, although the spec is not 100% clear about that). The JDBC 4.2 specification (section 14.1.2) says: _"The statement’s batch is reset to empty once `executeBatch` returns."_